# Paypal Issue: Reminder: REQUIRED to avoid service interruptions you need to complete important security upgrades. | wordpress website

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, paypal-sandbox

I have issue in my project. My project is working with Jupiter Theme. I have also used woocommerce plugin for display product and add to cart functionality. Now a day, there is facing the one **Paypal Issue** in my project.

**Error like this: Reminder: REQUIRED to avoid service interruptions you need to complete important security upgrades.**

Please guide me!!

Thanks...

Comment: Did you get an email from them?

Comment: yes I got the email from them

Comment: See my answer below please

Answer (score 0):

If you received and email that mentions "IPN Verification Postback to HTTPS" information", then please see https://www.paypal.com/au/webapps/mpp/ipn-verification-https

> To avoid any disruption of service, you must verify that your systems
>   are ready  for this change by June 30, 2018

This notice applies to IPN postbacks over HTTPS.